# SQL error: syntax error, unexpected '' (T_ENCAPSED_AND_WHITESPACE)

Tags: php, sql, database

Kindly do have a look at below mentioned SQL:

```
$sql ="INSERT INTO
    demo_participant
    (name, meeting_id_id, password, user_view__url, key, contact_no, email)
    VALUES
    ('$part_name', (SELECT id FROM demo_meeting WHERE meetingID = '$mtngid'),
    '$attendee_password', '$join_url', $getit_part['data'], '$pr_mobile',
    '$pr_email')";
```

My problem is the above statement is working fine without key and its associated value `$getit_part['data']`

But whenever I am trying to store key value I am getting the error i.e:

> **Parse error**:  syntax error, unexpected '' (T_ENCAPSED_AND_WHITESPACE), expecting identifier (T_STRING) or variable (T_VARIABLE) or number (T_NUM_STRING) in **/opt/lampp/htdocs/UI/user/joinmeeting.php** on line **86**

And when I am storing the value of `$getit_part['data']` in another variable like `$key`  then I am getting:

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'key,contact_no,email) VALUES('Rohitn',(SELECT id FROM demo_meeting WHERE ' at line 1

I know I am doing some syntax error but unable to debug it.

Comment: Can you simply Echo the $sql and show it ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`key` is a reserved word in MySQL. escape it with backticks

```
`key`
```

and you can't combine `select` and `values`. Try

```
INSERT INTO demo_participant(name, 
                             meeting_id_id, 
                             password, 
                             user_view__url, 
                             `key`, 
                             contact_no,
                             email)
SELECT '$part_name', 
       id, 
       '$attendee_password',
       '$join_url',
       '$getit_part['data']',
       '$pr_mobile',
       '$pr_email'
FROM demo_meeting
WHERE meetingID = '$mtngid'
```

Comment: <br />
<b>Parse error</b>:  syntax error, unexpected '' (T_ENCAPSED_AND_WHITESPACE), expecting identifier (T_STRING) or variable (T_VARIABLE) or number (T_NUM_STRING) in <b>/opt/lampp/htdocs/UI/user/joinmeeting.php</b> on line <b>87</b><br />

Comment: enclose `$getit_part['data']` in `{}` like in Tomak's answer.

Comment: yeah got it now thanks juergen d  and JYelton

Answer (score 0):

Encapsulate your array with curly braces:

```
$sql ="INSERT INTO
    demo_participant
    (name, meeting_id_id, password, user_view__url, key, contact_no, email)
    VALUES
    ('$part_name', (SELECT id FROM demo_meeting WHERE meetingID = '$mtngid'),
    '$attendee_password', '$join_url', {$getit_part['data']}, '$pr_mobile',
    '$pr_email')";
```

See Example #4 on [PHP Array Documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array.php):

> As in Perl, you can access a value from the array inside double quotes. However, with PHP you'll need to enclose your array between curly braces.

Comment: I'll leave this answer here, but @juergen is correct; the embedded `SELECT` needs to be rewritten as in his example.

Answer (score 0):

First error: You can put only simple variables like `$key` into SQL code. All expressions like array references (`$getit_part['data']`) need to be enclosed in `{}` for PHP to evaluate and substitute result as variables into SQL.

Second error: SQL syntax doesn't allow to put subqueries into `VALUES` clause of `INSERT` statement. Try using `INSERT ... SELECT ...` syntax instead, e.g.:

```
INSERT INTO dest (col1, col2)
SELECT val1, (SELECT val2 FROM table2 WHERE ...)
```

Notice that there's no `FROM` clause. You don't have to add it. It always selects single row this way.